# Makefile fails to run properly on Windows

Tags: windows, makefile

I'm trying to run my makefile but for some reason, **make** is not even able to run a simple "cls", all I get is:

make all_w

process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cls, ...) failed.
make (e=2): El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.
make: *** [all_w] Error 2

Here's my makefile:

```
all_l:
    make clean_all_l
    make lexer
    make lexerpiece_l

all_w:  
    cls
    # make clean_all_w
    # make parser
    # make lexer
    # make parserpiece_w

lexerpiece_l:
    gcc lex.yy.c -o lexerpiece_l -lfl -lm
    @echo Done

lexerpiece_w:
    gcc lex.yy.c -o lexerpiece_w -lfl -lm
    @echo Done

parserpiece_w:
    gcc lua_parser.tab.c lex.yy.c -lfl -lm -o parserpiece_w
    @echo Done

clean:  
    $(info Limpiando el Proyecto)
    -del lexerpiece.exe
    -del parserpiece.exe
    @echo Done

clean_all_w:
    $(info Realizando limpieza profunda)
    #cls
    -del lex.yy.c
    #-del lua_parser.tab.c
    #-del lua_parser.tab.h
    #-del lexerpiece_w.exe
    #-del parserpiece_w.exe
    #cls

clean_all_l:
    $(info Realizando limpieza profunda)
    -rm lex.yy.c
    -rm lexerpiece
    clear

#Esto corre FLEX y crea el nuevo lexer
lexer: 
    flex lua_lexer.l
    @echo Lexer creado

#Esto corre BISON y crea el nuevo parser
parser:
    bison -d lua_parser.y
    @echo Parser creado

#Esto correra FLEX sobre un archivo de testing
lexer_test:
    flex test.l
    @echo Lexer de prueba creado
```

Of course, I have updated the $PATH variable.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `cls` is a built-in command, not an executable.  `cmd /c cls` might work.

Comment: If you are not using Cygwin then this link might help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463037/calling-windows-commands-e-g-del-from-a-gnu-makefile

Comment: Using make on Windows can be a real pain. As you don't seem to be using some specific Windows stuff, I'd suggest switching, and use some "serious" (joke) OS. Things will suddenly become much more easier. If unable, install some distro into a virtualbox.

Comment: You are right, but my Ubuntu is broken since I moved to 14.01 and the graphics drivers stopped working... Some AMD vs Linux issue that I don't have time to solve now. The funny part is that the makefile I posted used to work!

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem trying to make with msys2. I have fixed adding this line of code to makefile:

```
SHELL=CMD
```

Additional information about this variable in [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html)