# run .exe from makefile on Windows

Tags: python, windows, makefile, conda

I have a python package that includes a commandline script. On windows that becomes LT.exe that is installed in my conda environment path.
I am using GNU make (from Rtools) to develop a pipeline of actions that include this commandline script, and python and R scripts. The problem is I can't get the commandline script to be recognized.

for example I want to run `make getpsII`

```
.PHONY : getpsII
getpsII :
    LT.exe --config $(SERVER_CONFIG)
```

running the .exe directly in WT or CMD in a conda shell works.  Launching it through make does not work.  I get

```
make[2]: C:/Users/dominikschneider/Miniconda3/envs/plantcv/Scripts/LT.exe: Command not found
```

I've tried appending LT.exe with cmd /c, setting SHELL=CMD in the make file, and giving it the absolute path to LT.exe

I assume this has something to do with how windows treats executables(?!) but any help would be appreciated.
I'm on WIndows 10. Thanks!

EDIT - tried setting PATH explicitly just before calliing the exe:

```
(plantcv) C:\Users\dominikschneider\Documents\phenomics\doi>make getpsII
setx /M PATH="C:/Users/dominikschneider/Miniconda3/envs/plantcv/Scripts;/Users/dominikschneider/Miniconda3/envs/plantcv:/Users/dominikschneider/Miniconda3/envs/plantcv/Library/mingw-w64/bin:/Users/dominikschneider/Miniconda3/envs/plantcv/Library/usr/bin:/Users/dominikschneider/Miniconda3/envs/plantcv/Library/bin:/Users/dominikschneider/Miniconda3/envs/plantcv/Scripts:/Users/dominikschneider/Miniconda3/envs/plantcv/bin:/Users/dominikschneider/Miniconda3/condabin:/Rtools/bin:/Program Files/Microsoft MPI/Bin:/Python27:/Python27/Scripts:/ProgramData/Boxstarter:/Rtools/bin:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin:/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/Windows/system32:/Windows:/Windows/System32/Wbem:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH:/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/Program Files/CMake/bin:/Program Files/dcraw:/Program Files/nodejs:/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/Users/dominikschneider/AppData/Local/Programs/orca:/Program Files/Pandoc:/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH:/WINDOWS/system32:/WINDOWS:/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/Program Files/Git LFS:/Program Files (x86)/Data Version Control:/Program Files/dotnet:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/Program Files/Git/cmd:/Users/dominikschneider/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/Scripts:/Users/dominikschneider/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32:/Users/Dominik Schneider/AppData/Local/atom/bin:/Users/Dominik Schneider/AppData/Roaming/npm:/Program Files (x86)/Nmap:/Users/dominikschneider/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/Users/dominikschneider/AppData/Local/GitHubDesktop/bin:/Users/dominikschneider/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code Insiders/bin:/Users/dominikschneider/AppData/Local/atom/bin:/Users/dominikschneider/appdata/local/atom/bin"

WARNING: The data being saved is truncated to 1024 characters.

SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.
LT-db-extractor --config ..//cppcserver.config --outdir data/psII --exper doi
make: LT-db-extractor: Command not found
make: *** [Makefile:93: getpsII] Error 127
```

Comment: You should try `./LT.exe`

Comment: Thanks Andreas but same result `make[2]: ./LT-db-extractor.exe: Command not found`

Comment: these suggestions also didn't work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463037/calling-windows-commands-e-g-del-from-a-gnu-makefile

Comment: Ok, just guessing. Now I see the windows path is wrong. You should use \ instead of /. And I don't like the look of that WARNING. Best print PATH after setting it and verify.

Comment: i'm not sure prepending the path matters. this `/Users/dominikschneider/Miniconda3/envs/plantcv/Scripts` is already in it.

Comment: if i add SHELL=cmd as first line  then it just opens a new cmd
```
(plantcv) C:\Users\dominikschneider\Documents\phenomics\doi>make getpsII
LT-db-extractor.exe --config ..//cppcserver.config --outdir data/psII --exper doi
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1082]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

(plantcv) C:\Users\dominikschneider\Documents\phenomics\doi>
```

Comment: I meant you paths on windows should be `C:\Users\dominikschneider\...`, not `C:/Users/dominikschneider/...`. And if setting SHELL=cmd I think you also need to set `.SHELLFLAGS` to whatever cmd need to "execute command", possibly `/c`.

Comment: i think you are right but I thought the point of SHELL=cmd is that it reads/formats your path correctly.

Comment: with .SHELLARGS=/c   I am getting 
(test-environment) C:\Users\dominikschneider\Documents\phenomics\doi>make getpsII
'ondabin:' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
make: *** [Makefile:92: getpsII] Error 1

so i think /condabin is in the path.

but I also notice that with `cmd /c LT-db-extractor.exe ` command is also not found so I don't know if that's the right SHELLARGS

Comment: i also tried //c and \/c

Answer (score 0):

in the end it turns out I had some _ and - confusion. I'll note that on Win 10 using Windows terminal I don't even need SHELL=CMD or SHELLARGS for this to work. Seems to translate perfectly between WSL and win conda shell!